# Browser freezing while using SetTimeOut in javascript to run a function which updates the UI

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using the below mentioned code to call a function(addCard) ,which adds images to the web page. The browser freezes due to this. If I call a simple function which does not update UI in setTimeOut, then the browser does not freeze. So, can't we update UI in the setTimeOut callback function. As far as I know, the javascript runtime for browser is single threaded. So, there is no separate UI thread. Then why is the browser freezing? As the callback will be run in the main thread. Here is the code:

```
 while(user.Score > dealer.Score){
        
        setTimeout(function(){addCard(dealer);},2000);
    }
```

Comment: Can you estimate the number of times the loop is executed, in the scenario that's causing the browser to freeze ?

Also, how are variables in the condition being incremented ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto variable in the condition are being incremented inside the addCard function, which is passed as callback in the setTimeOut call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your got stuck in infinity loop, since `user.Score > dealer.Score` will never be false. Also, you get recursion since you call the same function each 2 seconds, that creates recursion by itself. The browser, low out of memory, get stuck.

Comment: But if I call a simple function, which logs something to  console.  Then this problem does not occur. By this reasoning, that should also freeze the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The simple explanation for the browser to freeze is the browser running out of resources.

Since the `addCard(dealer)` function works when outside the setTimeout(), it leads me to believe the implementation with the timeout is the cause. The most obvious one being that the UI update is taking longer to complete than the time available to the thread. And since the while loop will keep executing, eventually the call stack will fill up. This will also explain why the browser freezes without throwing any errors.

You should be able to confirm this behavior by debugging the code. I would however recommend you modify the logic rather then trying a workaround to the issue.

Comment: The addCard() is not getting called. So, the UI update can not be the cause.

Comment: Ah ok. That information completely changes the question. Ended up going down a different route without it.

Comment: I think I understood the problem. The loop is continuously triggering the setTimeOut on the callstack.  Hence the callstack is never empty. So the callback functions of the setTimeOut which are in the callback queue never get invoked. It results in endless loop. I think that is what @Or Assayag was trying to say in his answer.

Comment: While that does sound logical, it isn't how timers work in javascript. Also, the call stack filling up in my explanation, not Assayag's. NodeJs docs has a very good explanation of timers in javascript : https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/